# React: How to get useEffect reducer function work with react-datepicker?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dispatch, react-datepicker, use-effect

I'm trying to get `useEffect` hook to show me user-chosen times after they pick them from dropdown. My co-worker helped me start the hook usage, but I'm completely lost on what should I do. After few days of attempts, I must ask for help.

At the moment, it correctly shows the time from the database, when the page is loaded, but gives `NaN`, when the user has chosen any number... Picture of correctly spawned table below (database values).

[image]

In short: `TimeClass` is the dropdown selection I'm trying to get the new time information (`reservations`) into `TimeChanger`. Everything is fine from there on out, it just saves into the database as I've planned.

**Main:**

```
export default () => {

  // collect the necessary information from the database
  const {data: reservationsData} = useAxios(`/api/reservations`);

  const [reservations, reservationsDispatch] = useReducer(reservationsReducer,reservationsData);
  useEffect(() => {
    reservationsDispatch({
      type: 'replace',
      data: reservationsData
    });
  }, [reservationsData]);

  const startPicker = reservations[row - 1].start_time;
  const endPicker = reservations[row - 1].end_time;
  const start = moment(startPicker, "hh:mm:ss").toDate();
  const end = moment(endPicker, "hh:mm:ss").toDate();

  //return everything
  return (
    <Page>
      { 
      // ... all code inside here is actually in other function, 
      // just trying to make it shorter and putting it here  
      }

      { _.times(2, (column)=>
        <TimeClass
          key={column}
          time={start} 
          endTime={end} 
          column={column} // creates 2 columns of times
          setTime={time => reservationsDispatch({
            type: 'setTime',
            row, // chooses, which row in the table the time goes
            col, // makes sure we are in col1, not confused with column
          })}
        />
      )}
      <TimeChanger
        row={row}
        reservations={reservations}
      />
    </Page>
  );
}
```

**TimeClass:**

```
function TimeClass ({ time, endTime, column, setTime }) {

  // changes "time", if needed
  if (column === 1) {
    time = endTime;
  }

  return (
      <DatePicker
        selected={time}
        onChange={setTime}
        showTimeSelect
        showTimeSelectOnly
        timeIntervals={15}
        timeCaption="Time"
      />
  );
}
```

**reservationReducer:**

```
function reservationsReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'replace':
      return action.data;
    case 'setTime':
      // what should be put here? How to get info here and out of here
      return TimeClass(/* what to return */);
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post your useAxios

Comment: What do you mean posting useAxios? I just imported it and get data from the database.

Comment: `useAxios` hook you are using

Comment: The only places `useAxios` is used in the file are imports and then the `const {data: reservationsData} = useAxios(´/api/reservations´); `

Comment: what im trying to ask you is the actual implementation of your `useAxios`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't quite understand, what you mean.. :D Do you mean the database table? Or something else?